# libkeyutils.so.1.8.1

Tags: linux, libraries, rkhunter, chkrootkit

I have noticed something I dont understand.

I have many servers hosted as VPS with Racknerd.

All my servers is installed with ubuntu 20.04.05 or 20.04.06.

All the servers installed before summer, have both libkeyutils.so.1.8.1 and libkeyutils.so.1.8. Servers installed after summer only have 1.8.

I have a server where I have only installed the Racknerd Ubuntu 20.04 image and nothing else, and it also have both versions of the file.

I'm unable to find any information regarding libkeyutils.so.1.8.1 and libkeyutils.so.1.8. It looks like the version of the complete package was increase from 1.6.x to a version called 2023, but I'm not able find find any information regarding which library versions are in the different packages.

I have checked with both rkhunter and chkrootkit and no rootkit was found.But some of AV at VT listed it as rootkit: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/2c23a23cf3df2659aeb5e6a778957b9038df51fd8386d7d5656f7b00a4cb1829

So can anyone explain what is going on, thank you in advance :)